# Data structure for storing job dependencies for job scheduler software

Tags: data-structures, graph, job-scheduling

I am writing a job scheduler. One of the functionality of my job scheduler is to handle job dependencies. for example: job A can define that do not run me until another job B finishes, or job A can define that do not run me until some file F exist in a disk etc.

In summary there are two types of dependencies I am handling

1. Dependency of a job on another job.
2. Dependency of a job on some infrastructure.

The requirement here is at any point of time someone can ask to generate a dependency graph of some job. To generate this graph efficiently I am looking for a format in which I should store these job dependencies. Please note that persistence is a file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG).

- **Directed**: to represent dependencies;
- **Acyclic**: to ensure that deadlock does not happen.

---

I guess then all that's needed knowing is how to store a graph.

IIRC, one way the acyclic nature of the graph is ensured is by running another algorithm in the background, which checks periodically if the current graph has a cycle and is deadlocked.

---

For the sake of completion, your graph vertices can store the following:

- **List of parent jobs** - the jobs that need to finish before this one can begin;
- **List of children jobs** - the jobs that can initiate only after this one has finished;
- **Job** - the detail of what this job itself is.

---

Further, since there may be a job or job group that doesn't depend on any other, therefore you may have a group of DAGs rather than just one DAG.